# Access/vba how to ceate server manager button in info tab with dsn less connection

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am converting an old Access/VBA database to Access 2010.  In the old project there was a "SERVER" button on the file->Info form that managed the connections to a SQL Database.  This provided a DSN less connection.  After creating the database and importing from the older version the button is no longer there.  I have been unable to find any reference to this and would like to know if anyone uses the same method for connecting and how to create the button.

[Server Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYnqF.png)

Comment: From the image it appears to be an .adp (Access Data Project) file which is now defunct in the newer versions of Access.   ODBC DSN-less connections can be made with some VBA: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/892490/how-to-create-a-dsn-less-connection-to-sql-server-for-linked-tables-in-access

Comment: That is true on the .adp and you have confirmed what I thought.  Like config files better anyway.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a button that calls this function.  Pass the name of the linked table (strName) and the DSN name (strODBC).

```
Function EditConString(strName$, strODBC$)

Dim DB As DAO.database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef

tablename = strName
'replace with the access link name

Set DB = CurrentDb()
Set tdf = DB.TableDefs(tablename)

tdf.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=" & strODBC
'replace with the ODBC connection DSN name
tdf.RefreshLink

Set tdf = Nothing
DB.Close

End Function
```